# Tensorflow - Errors in converting .pbtxt model to .tflite

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, classification

I am trying an example of car evaluation classification from
http://archive.ics.uci.edu/ml/datasets/Car+Evaluation

I have successfully trained model and printing predictions successfully
using following [code](https://gist.github.com/stonesarvesh/b6fe9bfb8759931dc81ee4439a241415)

I am following this [page](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/tree/master/tensorflow/contrib/lite) for converting `.pb` model to `.tflite`

I have successfully build frozen graph

```
bazel build tensorflow/python/tools:freeze_graph
```

Now I am facing problems in running following command

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph\
    --input_graph=/CarEvaluation/mobilenet_v1_224.pb \
    --input_checkpoint=/CarEvaluation/checkpoints/mobilenet-10202.ckpt \
    --input_binary=true --output_graph=/CarEvaluation/frozen_mobilenet_v1_224.pb \
    --output_node_names=CarEvaluation/Predictions/Reshape_1
```

Problem is that in model directory I have `.pbtxt` file instead of `.pb`
and also I couldn't find `.ckpt` file in model directory, I have a simple checkpoint file and several `.ckpt` meta and index files with some number as suffix.

I have tried running above command with .pbtxt file and I am getting this exception

```
   input_graph_def.ParseFromString(f.read())
google.protobuf.message.DecodeError: Error parsing message
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the .pbtxt and the highest numbered .ckpt

i.e. something like:

```
bazel-bin/tensorflow/python/tools/freeze_graph\
    --input_graph=/CarEvaluation/mobilenet_v1_224.pbtxt \
    --input_checkpoint=/CarEvaluation/checkpoints/mobilenet-10202.ckpt-2000 \
    --input_binary=true --output_graph=/CarEvaluation/frozen_mobilenet_v1_224.pb \
    --output_node_names=CarEvaluation/Predictions/Reshape_1
```

Answer (score 0):

As far as I have understood from the freeze_graph code, when you want to use it with a pbtxt file, you need to omit the --input_binary=true option, as the input file is no longer a binary one.